# Delete modules to clean namespace?

Tags: python, module, namespaces, package

I am working on a pretty huge Python package. Inside several modules, different programmers import other modules to do calculations. For the sake of this discussion, let's stick to `numpy`.

Common practice, when importing modules is defining an alias for easier programming, so let's say in a module `foo.py` there is a line doing

```
import numpy as np
```

So there will be a `foo.np` namespace. I also found out, that by deleting the reference to `np` inside `foo.py` by doing

```
del np
```

at the end of the module seems to clear the namespace as well.

As a maintainer of a huge package, I like this way of keeping the namespace clean but I wonder if this is good programming practice or if there are problems arising especially if my package has a module `bar.py` in the same level as `foo.py` which also uses the same external `numpy` module? If yes, is there a simple and better way to keep the namespaces of `foo` and `bar` clean or is this housekeeping of namespaces itself a bad idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a simple example:

`foo.py`:

```
import numpy as np

def foo(x):
    """Return 2D square array of zeros."""
    return np.zeros((x, x))

del np
```

`bar.py`:

```
import numpy as np

def bar():
    """Return 3x3 square array."""
    return np.arange(9).reshape(3, 3)
```

`main.py`:

```
from bar import bar
from foo import foo

print bar()

print foo(3)
```

And here are the outputs:

```
[[0 1 2]
 [3 4 5]
 [6 7 8]]

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jonrsharpe/Documents/main.py", line 6, in <module>
    print foo(3)
  File "/Users/jonrsharpe/Documents/foo.py", line 5, in foo
    return np.zeros((x, x))
NameError: global name 'np' is not defined
```

So clearly this has **not** affected `bar.py` (which you should expect - `del` removes *that reference*, but doesn't affect the underlying object) but has broken the functionality imported from `foo.py`, as `np` is no longer accessible to the objects defined in that file.

---

> is this housekeeping of namespaces itself a bad idea?

I'm not sure what you see as the *benefits* of it. Removing names from the namespace of a module you've finished using is not going to save very much (if any) space, and the underlying imported module (`numpy`, in this case) will still be in `sys.modules`.

Comment: Most people in my group use editors with auto-completion where every name in the namespace shows up. So it's basically just a convenience issue. Besides that, there are cases, where keeping the imports itself clean is a good way to prevent issues with circular imports. So I started thinking if cleaning the namespace inside every module was a good idea. And after your answer it clearly isn't.

Comment: @Dschoni you might find that doesn't make any difference anyway - I just tried in PyCharm, for example, and `import`ed names still autocomplete on lines subsequent to a `del` (and lines prior to the `import`, for that matter!)

Comment: This means, besides the possibility of clearing names from the namespace, it even doesn't do, what I expect it to...Thanks. Another reason to move away from Spyder.

Comment: @Dschoni I don't know if it would work in *any* IDE; it would have to hold different namespaces for autocomplete in different parts of a given file.

Comment: Cleaning up the namespace serves a very important purpose in the sense of making the package as intuitive to use for the user as well. Generally speaking, the python community has a lot to learn in terms of very basic user interfacing.